# ¿Como obtener el value de un input en PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-2.7

¿Alguien sabe como obtener el value con alguna libreria? 
Estoy intentando hacer scraping a un sitio de internet y la informacion que necesito la muestra pero en un input y nose como obtenerlo.
Gracias por la ayuda.
uno de los input:

```
<div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="" class="input-large nombre success" required="" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" title="BLANCO SERRANO" tabindex="-1">

                </div>
```

Comment: Prueba algo con las librerias scrapy o beautiful soup, después regresa y edita la pregunta con lo que has intentado.

Comment: Ya he intentado con beautiful inclusive tenia una pregunta pero no respondio nadie. Psd no funciono ya que visualmente el html no lo muestra

Comment: hay esta el detalle

Comment: Diego no se si es posible pero si lo es estaría bien que dejaras la página sobre la que quieres hacer el scraping indicando el input objetivo. BS es solo un parser, si el valor del input no está reflejado en el html no podrás obtener nada. Es posible que usando Selenium tengas más oportunidades al poder emular al completo el comportamiento de un navegador, incluida ejecución de código JS.

Comment: Solo la informacion de algunos input es moestrado en el html pero con una etiqueta de title dentro del input

Comment: Pero algunos datos no todos.

Comment: Lo extraño es que si intento editar lo que hay en los campos muestra un oldvalue pero eso solo pasa cuando lo hago personalmente no sabria como hacer lo desde python

Comment: @FJSevilla ... me podrias ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer para obtener el value de un input es primero seleccionar aquel input puesto que si hiciste `requests.get` a una pagina web habrán varios, seleccionas el input y agregas `.get('value')`. Ejemplo:

```
<div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="" class="input-large nombre success" required="" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" title="BLANCO SERRANO" tabindex="-1">

                </div>
```

Deberás colocar:

```
print(input.get('value'))
```

En mi caso habían varios input así que utilizaba:

```
print(input[4].get('value)
```

El numero 4 era porque seleccione el cuarto input.